# Math.tan (45) answer

Tags: javascript, math

In JavaScript, the function Math.tan(45); returns the value in radians, which is 1.6197751905438615. Basically, how would I get Math.tan(45) to return the answer 1?

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/tan.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, the answer is not in radians, as the answer is a fraction of lengths. You should rather use `Math.tan(45 * Math.PI / 180)` instead, since the argument has to be in radians.

Answer (score 2):

[`Math.tan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/tan) accepts radians, so you need to explicitly convert degrees to radians:

```
Math.tan(45 * Math.PI / 180);  // 0.9999999999999999
```